# Flink 1.11.1 off-heap Memory growing using RocksDbStateBackend

Tags: apache-flink

We are currently migrating from Flink 1.9 to Flink 1.11.1 and we are seeing an unexpected off heap memory consumption.
Our state is around 2TB and the used state backend is RocksDb.
To do a safe migration we choose to set :
`state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed` to true, as it is the default value starting from flink 1.10.

In production we are seeing that the task manager memory consumption is always going up and going way higher when we ask for a savepoint without cancel.
Please find here the screen of what we are seeing on one task manager :
[image: memory usage task manager screenshot]

Please find here the configuration that has been set :

```
taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size: 30720m
taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 35840m
taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: 20480m
taskmanager.memory.network.max: 5120m
```

Any advices on how we should ensure the capping of the memory usage ? Am i following the wrong track assuming that the problem is linked to RocksDbStateBackend ?

FYI. the 2 versions are running in parallel and only Flink 1.11.1 is acting this way.

Thanks

Comment: As a quick note, all the tasks manager are now unreachable due too the memory consumption. The limite has been reached after a savepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by setting:

> state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed = false

This is a known memory fragmentation issue in Flink 1.10.x and 1.11.x.
[JIRA Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19125).

I had a long [thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Debugging-quot-Container-is-running-beyond-physical-memory-limits-quot-on-YARN-for-a-long-running-stb-td38227.html) in Flink mailing list discussing the same.